# Checking and updating current users objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to change the current user's booleans and also check if the current user's booleans are true.  I have a working variable(user_id that shows the id of the user that posted it. Additionally users will only have one qr.

This is supposed to update the current users boolean:

```
 <%  @qr = Qr.index.update_attributes(clue1: true) %>
```

This checks is supposed to check if one of the booleans of the current user are true:

```
<% if @qr = Qr.index.clue1 == true %>
    Good job
  <% else %>
    You need to find the code!
<% end %>
```

Here is my qr controller:

```
class QrController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @qr = @user.Qr
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@qr)
  end

  def new
    @qrs = Qr.new
    respond_with(@qr)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @qr = Qr.new(qr_params)
    @qr = current_user.qr.build(params[:qr_params])
    @qr.created_by = current_user.id
    @qr.save
    redirect_to "/home/clues"
  end

  def update
    @qr.update(qr_params)
    respond_with(@qr)
  end

  def destroy
    @qr.destroy
    respond_with(@qr)
  end
end
```

User and Qr Models

```
class Qr < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

and

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     has_many :qrs
   end
```

TDLR: I can't tell if it's the current users model.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to find the value and set of an boolean from the current user

Comment: Basicly I can't find a  way to sense if its the current users model or a ramdom users, thanks for the help

Comment: if one user has many `qrs` then AR relation would be  `@user.qrs`

Comment: it's saying qr is undefined

Comment: Isn't it already defined from the controller?

Comment: you want a way to know if a certain qr belongs to the current user or not ?

Comment: no, I want a route to the current users qr, so I can change and view booleans stored in qr.

Comment: something like `/users/1/qrs` ?

Comment: no something like @qr.current_user.clue1 and so i could do something like `if @qr.current_user.clue1 == true` in a view

Comment: or something like this  `@qr = Qr.current_user.update_attributes(clue1: true)`  thanks!

Comment: @user3312633 so these clues belong to the user? and where do you want to make this changes, in the qr controller? create action for example?

Comment: Similar to the posts above i'm trying to change the db and these belong to the users. I made it create automaticly after account is created. the open a page that runs this `<% @qr = Qr.new
  @qr.update_attributes(user_id: current_user)
  @qr.update_attributes(clue1: false, clue2: false, clue3: false, clue4: false, clue5: false, clue6: false, clue6: false, clue7: false, clue8: false, clue9: false, clue10: false, clue11: false, clue12: false, clue13: false, clue14: false, clue15: false, done: false)
  @qr.save
  %>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to define

```
before_filter :set_user

private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

in your QrController

I hope it works

Comment: thanks, would i do something like this  to change it true, `@qr = Qr.set_user.update_attributes(clue1: true)` because it says set_user is undefined

Comment: can i have a look at usercontroller

Comment: I used devise I don't have one

Comment: then try use only :id not :user_id as a params

Comment: Ok the only thing is I tried running this ` @qr = Qr.find(1).user_id` and it worked

Comment: it said the same thing, undefined " set_user"

Comment: @qr - @user.Qr.find(params[:id])  try this

Comment: I got this undefined method `Qr' for nil:NilClass

Comment: if you controller name is Qr then you have to use qrs insted of Qr like: @qr= @user.qrs.find(params[:id])

Comment: Are you using @qr= @user.qrs.find(params[:id]) in your views/qr/

Comment: q  = qr.find(params[:id])                                                                                                          @qr= @user.q

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your code that a user only has access to its own Qr. So your routes will have something like

```
resources :qrs
```

(beware, controllers should always be in plural to work with automatic routing).

In this case, you can load the current user's QRs as

```
class QrsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @qrs = current_user.qrs
    # do things
  end

  def show
    @qr = current_user.qrs.find(params[:id])
    # do things
  end
  # ...
end
```

==Addendum==

The code you write in the view doesn't make much sense...

```
if @qr = Qr.index.clue1 == true
```

First of all you don't use actions (`index`) as helper functions or query functions.

Second, the `index` is an instance method of QrController (you could say `@qrc = QrController.new; @qrc.index`, but in any case controller's methods are not meant to be called by you, they correspond instead to specific routes/urls and the will be called by themselves), and not a class method of `Qr`.

Third, this code doesn't do what you expect:

```
if @qr = Qr.index.clue1 == true
```

is the same as

```
if @qr = (Qr.index.clue1 == true)
```

so it ends up assigning to the variable @qr a boolean value of `true` if the method `Qr.index.clue1` returns true, and of `false` otherwise.

The same applies to

```
Qr.index.update_attributes(clue1: true)
```

You are mixing up controller's actions and model finders in general.

Comment: it says `Couldn't find Qr without an ID`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these clues belong to qr

```
def create
  @qr = current_user.qrs.new(qr_params)
  @qr.assign_attributes(
    clue1 = true,
    clue2 = false,
    ...
  )
  if @qr.save
    redirect_to "/home/clues"
  else
    # handle failed save
  end
end
```

If they belong to user then replace with

```
@qr.user.assign_attributes
```

Then you need to save the user too

```
if @qr.save && @qr.user.save
```

Comment: it's sayin user is undefined.

Comment: `@user`? yea my bad, it should be `@qr.user.save`, i'll fix my answer

Comment: @user3312633 well idk, you need to tell me which line has the error

Comment: It is this `@qr.user.assign_attributes` user. Could user be undefined?

Comment: all im trying to do is get  a class that routes me to the qr of the current user

Comment: well you can replace it with `current_user.assign_attributes` and change `@qr.user.save` to `current_user.save` but idk why the first way is not working

Comment: I think I get why but don't know how to fix it, qr cant be pointed towards a user it has to be pointed towards which qr id it is. How can I creat a class that can tell what is the id of the qr for the current user.

Comment: you can call a method called `qr_ids` it will return an array with all `qr` ids the user has. `current_user.qr_ids`

Comment: that might work would it automatically choose one through or have the user pick because users will only have one.

Comment: if users will only have 1 `qr` then you need to fix the assocciation in the user model change it to `has_one :qr`, this way when you say `current_user.qr` it will return a qr object directly

Comment: do I need to define current_user?

Comment: current_user is a devise method, you only need change the association in the user model

Comment: would that load the qr id of the current user? I already changed it to has_one, Is that all I need to do?

Comment: no, calling `current_user.qr` will load a `qr` object, to get the id just chain id to the call, `current_user.qr.id`, you really need to read the assocciations guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: like i said, read the guide, i'm not gonna explain how basic associations work, it will take a lot of writing